# Google Drive NodeJS SDK: Upload file to a "real" account of Google Drive

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I have a Google Workspace account under my domain, let's call it `my.name@mydomain.com`.
And I want to upload a file to this drive using NodeJS Drive SDK.
According to the formal documentations, I created a service account on my GCP project, and I use a JSON key to authenticate my SDK instance.

When I upload the file, it uploads successfully so that the service-account is the owner of the file, and then I share it with `my.name@mydomain.com`.

Now since the **owner** of the file is the **service-account** the disk-space of the file is taken away from the service-account and not from `my.name@mydomain.com`.

How can I upload a file on behalf of `my.name@mydomain.com` instead of the service-account's?

Thanks

Comment: I am guessing you’ll need to do some sort of oauth

Comment: How exactly do I do it?